# Make SVG graphics play on entering window (scroll)

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a tough question! I have several SVG graphics on some of my pages which play when the page loads. But because many of them are below the fold, I would like them to start playing (and play once) when they scroll into view.

NOTE: I have searched everywhere for a solution and even hired a freelancer who couldn't make it work. The difference with my SVGs I think is that they use @keyframe and have more than one path that play in sequence which may be why other solutions do not work? The reason for more than one path is that it is a calligraphic arrow shape that overlaps when revealed by the SVG mask.

My HTML for one of the SVGs (inside a DIV to make it responsive):

```html
<div id="arrow-1id" class="arrow-1 leftarrows">
  <!--START ARROW 1-->
  <svg id="arrow1svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 436.55 256.959">
                        
                        <mask id="arrow1-mask1" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                        <path d="M4.537,54.288
                            c96.333-80.667,213.667,135.333,90.667,96.333"/>
                        </mask>
                        
                        <mask id="arrow1-mask2" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                        <path d="M100.87,156.955
                            c-29.667-100.667,29.666-152,78.333-146.667s151.667,255.667,29.667,234"/>
                        </mask>
                        
                        <mask id="arrow1-mask3" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                        <path d="M214.87,248.956
                            c-53.667-43.667,15.334-337.334,195.667-169.667"/>
                        </mask>
                        
                        <mask id="arrow1-mask4" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                        <path d="M322.203,53.955c108.667,43,117,69.09,68-53.955"/>
                        </mask>
                        
                            <path mask="url(#arrow1-mask1)" fill="#42A8FC" d="M98.168,50.639C66.146,29.84,27.535,21.405,0.142,44.781c-1.983,1.692,17.501,16.275,21.915,12.509
                            c21.17-18.066,49.736-15.119,72.854-0.936c11.126,6.518,19.094,15.658,19.094,15.658c8.426,9.078,14.961,19.84,18.385,31.416
                            c4.701,15.891,0.705,30.535-10.91,41.153c-0.855,0.782-1.803,1.409-2.783,1.981c-0.01,0.004-6.326,4.56-16.162,2.465l-6.889,7.466
                            c9.913,8.681,22.827,13.119,36.498,7.999c43.123-16.156,23.759-65.003-14.488-98.967C117.654,65.526,108.286,57.122,98.168,50.639z"/>
                            
                            <path mask="url(#arrow1-mask2)" fill="#42A8FC" d="M231.959,50.614c-17.516-25.197-43.061-49.605-73.761-50.592c-20.618-0.664-34.757,13.81-44.931,27.774
                            c-5.189,7.124-10.349,14.789-15.1,22.843l-3.258,5.715C84.467,75.328,76.75,96.273,76.766,117.7
                            c0.01,13.138,7.45,28.785,18.879,38.794l6.889-7.466c-0.658-1.355-1.329-2.721-1.771-4.061
                            c-7.573-22.907,0.716-49.699,13.241-72.955l3.65-6.486c7.376-12.557,15.713-23.818,23.057-32.426
                            c8.87-10.398,23.658-23.112,40.648-19.129c14.01,3.285,24.33,19.391,31.584,30.21c3.548,5.288,7.105,11.241,10.578,17.655
                            l12.133,25.446c22.227,53.15,32.844,122.106-8.789,151.369c-3.873,2.722-8.496,4.636-12.935,6.029l-3.878,7.245
                            c25.657,15.113,52.242-6.228,60.439-31.938c14.138-44.338-1.676-101.902-24.266-145.678
                            C246.227,74.311,238.632,60.523,231.959,50.614z"/>
                            
                            <path mask="url(#arrow1-mask3)" fill="#42A8FC" d="M406.734,68.147c-17.148-17.841-37.951-33.412-59.953-44.124c-50.594-24.632-88.095-5.991-114.822,26.591
                            l-8.438,11.223c-3.395,4.914-6.599,10.027-9.592,15.281c-17.29,30.335-29.316,64.641-31.375,100.486
                            c-1.105,19.22-1.053,44.238,13.145,61.586c4.664,5.7,9.492,9.873,14.354,12.736l3.878-7.245c-3.323-4.796-5.046-11.189-6.378-16.149
                            c-5.317-19.783-3.871-40.435-0.658-59.469c4.553-26.978,14.076-56.253,28.76-81.78l9.521-14.934
                            c8.408-11.894,18.098-22.568,29.177-31.183c41.766-32.474,90.141-8.049,122.342,30.429
                            C404.036,81.622,413.766,75.922,406.734,68.147z"/>
                            
                            <path mask="url(#arrow1-mask4)" fill="#42A8FC" d="M404.413,71.956c0,0-3.166,0-12.344-3.026c-17.545-5.735-35.092-11.471-52.635-17.206
                            c-15.207-4.971-15.507,16.587-1.976,21.011c27.503,8.99,55.004,17.981,82.506,26.972c9.534,3.115,13.706-5.336,11.287-12.662
                            c-8.52-25.797-17.039-51.594-25.558-77.392c-4.546-13.767-25.338-10.047-20.597,4.315c5.671,17.17,11.341,34.342,17.013,51.514
                            L404.413,71.956z"/>
                        
                        </svg>

  <style>
    #arrow1-mask1 path {
      fill: none;
      stroke: white;
      stroke-width: 39;
      stroke-dasharray: 265.809 265.809;
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      animation: brush1a 2s linear;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    #arrow1-mask2 path {
      fill: none;
      stroke: white;
      stroke-width: 39;
      stroke-dasharray: 499.444 499.444;
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      animation: brush1b 2s linear;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    #arrow1-mask3 path {
      fill: none;
      stroke: white;
      stroke-width: 39;
      stroke-dasharray: 396.144 396.144;
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      animation: brush1c 2s linear;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    #arrow1-mask4 path {
      fill: none;
      stroke: white;
      stroke-width: 39;
      stroke-dasharray: 195.971 195.971;
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      animation: brush1d 2s linear;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    @keyframes brush1a {
      0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 265.809;
      }
      1% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 265.809;
      }
      20% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
      100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes brush1b {
      0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 499.444;
      }
      20% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 499.444;
      }
      60% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
      100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes brush1c {
      0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 396.144;
      }
      60% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 396.144;
      }
      80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
      100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes brush1d {
      0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 195.971;
      }
      80% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 195.971;
      }
      100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <!--END ARROW 1-->
</div>
```

I haven't posted any JS because none of the code I have tried works.

Comment: You want SVGs animate when it's visible on-page right ?. ex some of the SVGs come when you scroll down and then animate

Comment: @Aman yes that is correct. I have multiple SVGs down the page and i need each one to play when they appear on screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by running the animation if the container `#arrow-1id` as a specific class (lets say `.play`). Then you just check with javascript when the container appear in the screen. When it's the case, just add the `.play` class to the container:

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var div = document.getElementById("arrow-1id");

body.onscroll = function() {
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >= div.offsetTop - 200) {
    div.classList.add("play");
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

#arrow-1id {
  margin-top: 400px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.play #arrow1-mask1 path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 39;
  stroke-dasharray: 265.809 265.809;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: brush1a 2s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.play #arrow1-mask2 path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 39;
  stroke-dasharray: 499.444 499.444;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: brush1b 2s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.play #arrow1-mask3 path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 39;
  stroke-dasharray: 396.144 396.144;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: brush1c 2s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.play #arrow1-mask4 path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 39;
  stroke-dasharray: 195.971 195.971;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: brush1d 2s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes brush1a {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 265.809;
  }
  1% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 265.809;
  }
  20% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes brush1b {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 499.444;
  }
  20% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 499.444;
  }
  60% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes brush1c {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 396.144;
  }
  60% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 396.144;
  }
  80% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes brush1d {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 195.971;
  }
  80% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 195.971;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="arrow-1id" class="arrow-1 leftarrows">
  <!--START ARROW 1-->
  <svg id="arrow1svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 436.55 256.959">

    <mask id="arrow1-mask1" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path d="M4.537,54.288
                            c96.333-80.667,213.667,135.333,90.667,96.333" />
    </mask>

    <mask id="arrow1-mask2" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path d="M100.87,156.955
                            c-29.667-100.667,29.666-152,78.333-146.667s151.667,255.667,29.667,234" />
    </mask>

    <mask id="arrow1-mask3" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path d="M214.87,248.956
                            c-53.667-43.667,15.334-337.334,195.667-169.667" />
    </mask>

    <mask id="arrow1-mask4" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path d="M322.203,53.955c108.667,43,117,69.09,68-53.955" />
    </mask>

    <path mask="url(#arrow1-mask1)" fill="#42A8FC" d="M98.168,50.639C66.146,29.84,27.535,21.405,0.142,44.781c-1.983,1.692,17.501,16.275,21.915,12.509
                            c21.17-18.066,49.736-15.119,72.854-0.936c11.126,6.518,19.094,15.658,19.094,15.658c8.426,9.078,14.961,19.84,18.385,31.416
                            c4.701,15.891,0.705,30.535-10.91,41.153c-0.855,0.782-1.803,1.409-2.783,1.981c-0.01,0.004-6.326,4.56-16.162,2.465l-6.889,7.466
                            c9.913,8.681,22.827,13.119,36.498,7.999c43.123-16.156,23.759-65.003-14.488-98.967C117.654,65.526,108.286,57.122,98.168,50.639z" />

    <path mask="url(#arrow1-mask2)" fill="#42A8FC" d="M231.959,50.614c-17.516-25.197-43.061-49.605-73.761-50.592c-20.618-0.664-34.757,13.81-44.931,27.774
                            c-5.189,7.124-10.349,14.789-15.1,22.843l-3.258,5.715C84.467,75.328,76.75,96.273,76.766,117.7
                            c0.01,13.138,7.45,28.785,18.879,38.794l6.889-7.466c-0.658-1.355-1.329-2.721-1.771-4.061
                            c-7.573-22.907,0.716-49.699,13.241-72.955l3.65-6.486c7.376-12.557,15.713-23.818,23.057-32.426
                            c8.87-10.398,23.658-23.112,40.648-19.129c14.01,3.285,24.33,19.391,31.584,30.21c3.548,5.288,7.105,11.241,10.578,17.655
                            l12.133,25.446c22.227,53.15,32.844,122.106-8.789,151.369c-3.873,2.722-8.496,4.636-12.935,6.029l-3.878,7.245
                            c25.657,15.113,52.242-6.228,60.439-31.938c14.138-44.338-1.676-101.902-24.266-145.678
                            C246.227,74.311,238.632,60.523,231.959,50.614z" />

    <path mask="url(#arrow1-mask3)" fill="#42A8FC" d="M406.734,68.147c-17.148-17.841-37.951-33.412-59.953-44.124c-50.594-24.632-88.095-5.991-114.822,26.591
                            l-8.438,11.223c-3.395,4.914-6.599,10.027-9.592,15.281c-17.29,30.335-29.316,64.641-31.375,100.486
                            c-1.105,19.22-1.053,44.238,13.145,61.586c4.664,5.7,9.492,9.873,14.354,12.736l3.878-7.245c-3.323-4.796-5.046-11.189-6.378-16.149
                            c-5.317-19.783-3.871-40.435-0.658-59.469c4.553-26.978,14.076-56.253,28.76-81.78l9.521-14.934
                            c8.408-11.894,18.098-22.568,29.177-31.183c41.766-32.474,90.141-8.049,122.342,30.429
                            C404.036,81.622,413.766,75.922,406.734,68.147z" />

    <path mask="url(#arrow1-mask4)" fill="#42A8FC" d="M404.413,71.956c0,0-3.166,0-12.344-3.026c-17.545-5.735-35.092-11.471-52.635-17.206
                            c-15.207-4.971-15.507,16.587-1.976,21.011c27.503,8.99,55.004,17.981,82.506,26.972c9.534,3.115,13.706-5.336,11.287-12.662
                            c-8.52-25.797-17.039-51.594-25.558-77.392c-4.546-13.767-25.338-10.047-20.597,4.315c5.671,17.17,11.341,34.342,17.013,51.514
                            L404.413,71.956z" />

  </svg>


  <!--END ARROW 1-->
</div>
```

Comment: johannchopin, you are a legend, this seems to work but only for one svg. The problem is that when i try to implement it with a second (and even a third) svg, they all play at the same time. I need each one to play when they appear onscreen. I think the body height is the issue but i cant change this for every svg.

Comment: Please upvote and validate my answer and I will share you an example which work with multiples svg (because in the question you only mentionned one svg).

Comment: thanks johannchopin. "I have several SVG graphics on some of my pages" hope you can help. please see my own answer with the code i found is working best but only in Firefox apparently...?  (i could no longer edit my original post) But keen to see your solution if it works better! Im sure it will help many others also.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works but it seems only supported in Firefox, no other browser???

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
                var diva2 = document.getElementById("arrow-2id");
                
                window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
                  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop >= diva2.offsetTop - -500) {
                    diva2.classList.add("play");
                  }
                  
                 }
                );
                </script>
```